# Validate user login php

Tags: php, validation, authentication

Quick question... I got my login page working right now so that when the user enters the correct information it will redirect them to the home page in a session. When they enter the wrong information it will just redirect them back to the login page.

What I am trying to do, is when they type the wrong information I want it to still redirect them to the login page but I want it to say invalid login, please try again. I tried to echo that but it just refreshes the page no echo on it..

Login page

```
<?php include '../../view/header.php'; ?>
<div id="main">
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if user is already login, then jump to secured page
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: ../../admin');
}

?>

<html>

<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>

<h3>Admin Login</h3>

<table>
<form method="POST" action="loginproc.php">
<tr><td>Username</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td>:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td></tr>
</form>
</table>

</body>

</html>
</div>
<?php include '../../view/footer.php'; ?>
```

loginproc.php

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
require_once('database.php');

// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and (password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "')");




// Check username and password match
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
// Set username session variable
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
// Jump to secured page
header('Location: ../../admin');
}
else {
// Jump to login page

header('Location: index.php');

}

?>
```

Comment: You can add GET params in the redirect: `header('location: url/page?loginfail=1');`

Comment: Be aware sessions can be easily hijacked if you don't add more security to them (such as checking back the session IP vs REMOTE_ADDR, etc.

Comment: This question gets asked several times every week. You will certainly find answers if you search the previous questions about this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php include '../../view/header.php'; ?>
<div id="main">
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if user is already login, then jump to secured page
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: ../../admin');
}
else if (isset($_GET['loginfail']) {
    echo "Please try again later";
}
?>

<html>

<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>

<h3>Admin Login</h3>

<table>
<form method="POST" action="loginproc.php">
<tr><td>Username</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td>:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td></tr>
</form>
</table>

</body>
```

loginproc.php

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
require_once('database.php');

// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and (password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "')");




// Check username and password match
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
// Set username session variable
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
// Jump to secured page
header('Location: ../../admin');
}
else {
// Jump to login page

header('Location: index.php?loginfail=1');

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt use any output before redirect. It may work, but It can also print out error without redirect.

As for redirect and output. You can store some information to `SESSION`, do redirect and then print out error according to `SESSION`. If your error reporting is only somthing simple, you can use `GET` and pass that in parametr via redirect page.